# What's the meaning of semi-colon in transact-sql?

Tags: t-sql

Use AdventureWorks;
GO

What's the meaning of semi-colon after AdventureWorks? Is that to signal the end of the statement? In that case, what the point of having GO.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Go is a very very old remnant of when SQL server was still a SYBASE product (later phagocyted by Microsoft).  It divides blocks of commands into batches or standalone commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GO --> Signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL Server utilities. This could be multiple lines with semi-colons on the end depending on the structure of the t-sql.

EDIT: Some times at work we create proc scripts that have permissions appended at the end, if you run the create proc without a GO at the end the permissions error because you are trying to grant access to a proc that hasn't been created. GO forces the creation of the proc before you apply the appropriate permissions.

Comment: The ; signifies the end of a statement but as with a proc there can be multiple statements declared before the batch is committed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an article on SQLServerCentral about GO and semicolon.
Semicolon is statement terminator and GO is a batch terminator.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Puzzles/thegocommandandthesemicolonterminator/2200/